# openCV Storagefile Error :

Tags: c++, file, opencv, matrix

I am trying to load a matrix from .yaml file but opencv gives me the following error :

> OpenCV Error: Parsing Error (myFile.yaml(1): valid xml should start with ')
>   OpenCV Error: Parsing Error (myFile.yaml(1): Tag should start with '<'> in unknown function)

this is my Write into Storage file, whcih works fine :

```
cv::FileStorage fs("myFile.yaml", cv::FileStorage::APPEND);   
while(counter<_imgPtrVector.size()){    
    unsigned char* _pointer=(unsigned char*)_imgPtrVector.at(counter);
    cv::Mat _matrixImage(cv::Size( width,height), CV_8UC1,_pointer , cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);       
    fs <<"Matrix"<<_matrixImage;
    counter++;
}
```

but when I want to load the data from the same file I got those errors; this is the code for Reading from storage file :

```
cv::FileStorage f("myFile.yaml", cv::FileStorage::READ );
cv::Mat mat(cv::Size( width,height), CV_8UC1);  
if(f.isOpened()){
    cv::FileNode n = f["Matrix"];
    if (n.type() != cv::FileNode::SEQ){
     std::cout << "error!";
    }
    f["Matrix"] >>  mat; 
}
```

Comment: If you have further information to add, please include it by editing your own question.  Please don't edit somebody else's answer, because that makes it look like they wrote what you actually wrote.

Comment: hi Luke Sorry about it, I done it with no intention.

Comment: The other thing about editing your own question is that the edits appear immediately.  If you edit someone else's answer, those edits have to be approved by other users before they show up, and they might never show up if the edits are rejected.  It appears that your edits to karl's answer have indeed been rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you are always appending to an existing file. So you might have to change your code to:

```
FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
```

This will recreate the file each time your program runs.

The OpenCV docs have an example on [how to **write**](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#xml-yaml-file-storages-writing-to-a-file-storage) with XML/YAML Persistence that is pretty clear:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

    fs << "frameCount" << 5;
    time_t rawtime; time(&rawtime);
    fs << "calibrationDate" << asctime(localtime(&rawtime));
    Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1000, 0, 320, 0, 1000, 240, 0, 0, 1);
    Mat distCoeffs = (Mat_<double>(5,1) << 0.1, 0.01, -0.001, 0, 0);
    fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
    fs << "features" << "[";
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        int x = rand() % 640;
        int y = rand() % 480;
        uchar lbp = rand() % 256;

        fs << "{:" << "x" << x << "y" << y << "lbp" << "[:";
        for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
            fs << ((lbp >> j) & 1);
        fs << "]" << "}";
    }
    fs << "]";
    fs.release();
    return 0;
}
```

And there is another example that shows [how to **read**](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#reading-data-from-a-file-storage).

Comment: Thank the link was so useful. Just one more question, I need to pass this file to another person in our team to process the matrices in matlab, I understand there is an yamlmatlab library to read the file, but do you know if opencv give us any other format file to save the matrices for matlab? please let me know thank you

Comment: There seems to be something related to MEX, but I"m not sure what it is.

Comment: thank you, it is interesting when I run the code with both write into file first and close the stream, and read from file, the code works fine. but when I want to just read my data from the stored file it gives me the same exceptions.

Comment: That is most probably a bug in your code. Can't really tell without looking at it. But the OpenCV demos work flawlessly on my machine so you should pay extra attention to what you are doing. Remember to close the file between write/read.